# Having NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener Communicate back to Referencing csproj

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, nunit

I have successfully implement a concrete class, called `TestEventListener`, that implements `NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener` in a csproj called *NunitExtension*. My test csproj is called *ParentTests* of which references *NunitExtension*. I have work that a class, `RunningTest`, in *ParentTests* that needs to act upon what the `TestEventListener` heard.

From my limited understanding, I believe that NUnit via reflection creates `TestEventListener` because `TestEventListener` implements `NUnit.Engine.Extensibility.ExtensionAttribute` and
`NUnit.Engine.Extensibility.ITestEventListener`. As I was learning what I can do, I realized that I am not able have `TestEventListener` communicate back to `RunningTest`. I am presuming they are on different threads, because the ids are different in Visual Studio - Worker Thread and EventPumpThread, respectively. What I am not sure of is what is the best practice of having `TestEventListener` communication data back to `RunningTest`?

---

Answering @Chris comment about what the goal is :

Some very smart and creative people have figured out how to batch process data driven test using the `TestCaseSourceAttribute`. Programmatically an `IEnumerable` of tests cases is created that `TestCaseSourceAttribute` uses. The test cases objects are created from Json files. Within the hydrated object, we know what to test and what to assert. It is very ingenious.

We want to replace a script at the end of the test run that takes the results test xml coupled with additional files to generate a report on what was just ran. The additional files have the test meta data (i.e. test description, test category, and some specific data points). From the `ITestEventListener` in memory I know the 1) test status, 2) test id, 3) when a given test finishes, 4) when the entire batch tests process finishes, and 4) I am able to parse the messages for additional information for the report. I still need to render information based off the test id from the Json file. There was hope we could do all the work in memory after `ITestEventListener` informs us that the tests are complete and not have to read (i.e. IO) files again. The thought was that we could use the `ITestEventListener` and do everything in memory; not knowing that `ITestEventListener` is on a different thread in a different app pool.

Comment: Are the threads from different app domains?

Comment: Yes, they will be. This isn't really what TestEventListeners are intended for - they're more of a one-way interface. Could you add details about what you're trying to achieve, and people might be able to suggest another way?